# Не могу разобраться с параметрами кватерниона

Tags: вычислительная-геометрия

Вот что я нашел:

```
Всего у кватерниона четыре компоненты: X, Y, Z и W. 
XYZ — ось поворота, W — угол поворота.
```

У меня сразу возник вопрос, **как** ось может описана координатами одной точки, ведь что бы определить направление оси нужно хотя бы две точки через которые можно провести прямую линию?

Вопрос: **где** находится вторая точка?

Answer (score 7):

Кватернион - это четырех-мерное комплексное число, операции с ним следуют аналогичным правилам комплексной алгебры.

q  = x  + y*i* + z*j* + w*k*

i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = −1

ij = - ji = k

ki = - ik = j

jk = - kj = i

**Метрика (длина, магнитуда, модуль)** кватерниона вычисляется как его метрика в эвклидовом 4-хмерном пространстве, то есть

|q| = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z + w*w)

**Сопряженный кватернион** p = conjugate(q), это такой кватернион, что верно выражение:

conjugate(pq) = conjugate(q) conjugate(p),

conjugate(p) = q

conjugate(conjugate(q)) = q

**Кватернион нулевого вращения**, называемый identity или unity

q = k или  q = {0, 0, 0, 1}

Его часто переводят как единичный, по аналогии с единичной матрицей, однако в русской терминологии единичный кватернион, как и единичный вектор, закреплено за произвольным вектором с метрикой 1.

"Фишка" использования кватерниона в том, что с помощью единичного кватерниона можно **однозначно** представить любой поворот по сфере. Он иммунен к "складыванию рамок" - термин, относящийся к области гироскопии и инерциальной навигации, событие, которое может происходить в том случае, когда внутренняя рамка гироскопа повернётся на 90 градусов относительно наружной рамки, и при этом вектор кинетического момента будет направлен по оси наружной рамки - возникающему при использовании углов Эйлера и аналогичном повороте на 90 градусов.

У меня в проекте был вот такой комментарий, там написано как в действительности определено вращение, через кватернион

```
// Что такое кватернион?
// ---------------------
// кватернион - это точка в  4-мерном комплексном пространстве.
// Q = { Qx, Qy, Qz, Qw }
// 
// Зачем нужны кватернионы?
// ------------------------
// Множество всех кватернионов, принадлежащих сфере с радиусом 1
// соответствует множеству всех возможных преобразований вращения в 
// трехмерном эвклидовом пространстве. Вращение проще описать
// в пространстве кватернионов, чем в пространстве матриц вращения.
// * Кватернион идентичен 4хмерному вектору, проще хранить в массивах,
// в виде float или _m128
// * Нет проблемы выбора способа хранения
// * Умножение вектора на кватернион содержит меньше умножений
// 
// Как использовать кватернионы?
// -----------------------------
// Следует знать как получить кватернион из матрицы и  наооборот
// Поворот вектора v может быть записан следующим образом:
// 
//  v' = v * R (для вектора-строки)
//
// 1) вектор v' описывает ту же точку в другой системе координат
// 2) вектор v' описывает точку, повернутую в соответствии с 
// параметрами преобразования
```

**Кватернионы и вращение вокруг оси**

"XYZ — ось поворота, W — угол поворота" неверное определение в принципе, так как общем случае кватернион не определяет поворот. Если же речь о единичном кватернионе, то по аналогии с двумерным пространством, w - косинус половины угла поворота, XYZ - вектор, параллельный оси вращения, такой что метрика кватениона равна единице (мат. вывод можно посмотреть в Википедии)

```
// Предположим  мы хотим записать поворот на угол (theta) 
// вокруг оси , описанной единичным вектором ({Ax, Ay, Az})...
//
// s = sin(0.5 * theta)
// c = cos(0.5 * theta)
// Q = { s * Ax, s * Ay, s * Az, c }
//
// Если вектор А единичен, то метрика кветерниона тоже.
//
// Матрица 3x3 , соответствующая кватерниону
// -----------------------------------------
// Q = { x, y, z ,w }
//
//     |                                                                    |
//     | 1 - 2 * (y^2 + z^2)   2 * (x * y + z * w)     2 * (y * w - x * z)  |
//     |                                                                    |
// M = | 2 * (x * y - z * w)   1 - 2 * (x^2 + z^2)     2 * (y * z + x * w)  |
//     |                                                                    |
//     | 2 * (x * z + y * w)   2 * (y * z - x * w)     1 - 2 * (x^2 + y^2)  |
//     |                                                                    |
```

Из углов Эйлера и в углы Эйлера легче всего преобразовывать через матрицу, или аккуратно сделать свертку этой операции. Здесь следует помнить что при вычислении тригонометрических функций допустимы погрешности и результат может "дрожать", нужно следить чтобы получаемая матрица была ортогональной, а кватернион - единичным. Оттуда же:

```
inline F32  CQuaternion::normalize()
{
    F32 mag = sqrtf(mQ[VX]*mQ[VX] + mQ[VY]*mQ[VY] + mQ[VZ]*mQ[VZ] + mQ[VS]*mQ[VS]);

    if (mag > FP_MAG_THRESHOLD)
    {
            // Неточности операций могут помешать кватерниону достичь 
            // единичной длинны, при попытках перенормировки такого
            // кватерниона возникает "болтанка", "джиттер" между
            // соседними квантовыми значениями. Поэтому нормирование 
            // происходит только тогда, когда разница между метрикой 
            // и единицей велика.
        if (fabs(1.f - mag) > ONE_PART_IN_A_MILLION)
        {
            F32 oomag = 1.f/mag;
            mQ[VX] *= oomag;
            mQ[VY] *= oomag;
            mQ[VZ] *= oomag;
            mQ[VS] *= oomag;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // кватернион совсем плох из-за малого угла, 
            // заменяем его на единичный c нулевым поворотом
        mQ[VX] = 0.f;
        mQ[VY] = 0.f;
        mQ[VZ] = 0.f;
        mQ[VS] = 1.f;
    }

    return mag;
}
```

Зададим вращение вокруг оси

```
const CQuaternion&  CQuaternion::setAngleAxis(F32 angle, const CVector4F &vec)
{
    CVector3F v(vec.mV[VX], vec.mV[VY], vec.mV[VZ]);
    v.normalize();

    F32 c, s;
    c = cosf(angle*0.5f);
    s = sinf(angle*0.5f);

    mQ[VX] = v.mV[VX]*s;
    mQ[VY] = v.mV[VY]*s;
    mQ[VZ] = v.mV[VZ]*s;
    mQ[VW] = c;

    normalize();
    return (*this);
}
```

Стратегия преобразования

```
const CQuaternion&  CQuaternion::setEulerAngles(F32 roll, F32 pitch, F32 yaw)
{
    CMatrix3 rot_mat(roll, pitch, yaw);
    rot_mat.orthogonalize();
    *this = rot_mat.quaternion();

    normalize();
    return (*this);
}

void CQuaternion::getEulerAngles(F32 *roll, F32 *pitch, F32 *yaw) const
{
    CMatrix3 rot_mat(*this);
    rot_mat.orthogonalize();
    rot_mat.getEulerAngles(roll, pitch, yaw);
}
```

У меня используются вектора строки, поэтому матрицы транспонированные (именно так они хранятся в OpenGL) и умножения задом-наперед

**Поворот вектора**

Поворот вектора осуществляется путем умножения на кватернион и на его сопряженное значение с разных сторон

```
// Канон:
//       v1 = q *v * conjugate(q)
//
// Есть оптимизированный метод (35% быстрее если используется SSE2, 40%-50% в GLSL), записано в GLSL
// 
//      t = 2*cross (q.xyz, v)              
//      v1 = v + q.w * t + cross(q.xyz, t)
// 
CVector4F       operator*(const CVector4F &a, const CQuaternion &rot)
{
    F32 rw = - rot.mQ[VX] * a.mV[VX] - rot.mQ[VY] * a.mV[VY] - rot.mQ[VZ] * a.mV[VZ];
    F32 rx =   rot.mQ[VW] * a.mV[VX] + rot.mQ[VY] * a.mV[VZ] - rot.mQ[VZ] * a.mV[VY];
    F32 ry =   rot.mQ[VW] * a.mV[VY] + rot.mQ[VZ] * a.mV[VX] - rot.mQ[VX] * a.mV[VZ];
    F32 rz =   rot.mQ[VW] * a.mV[VZ] + rot.mQ[VX] * a.mV[VY] - rot.mQ[VY] * a.mV[VX];

    F32 nx = - rw * rot.mQ[VX] +  rx * rot.mQ[VW] - ry * rot.mQ[VZ] + rz * rot.mQ[VY];
    F32 ny = - rw * rot.mQ[VY] +  ry * rot.mQ[VW] - rz * rot.mQ[VX] + rx * rot.mQ[VZ];
    F32 nz = - rw * rot.mQ[VZ] +  rz * rot.mQ[VW] - rx * rot.mQ[VY] + ry * rot.mQ[VX];

    return CVector4F(nx, ny, nz, a.mV[VW]);
}
```

Comment: объясните что такое `метрика кватениона`

Comment: @perfect вычисляется как и метрика любого вектора в эвклидовом. добавил.

Answer (score 3):

XYZ - не координаты точки, а координаты вектора. А вектор может определить ось.

UPD. [Координаты вектора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F)#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B4.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5) - не координаты точки, а коэффициенты базисных векторов. Можно считать, что вектор, с координатами (1, 2) - это вектор из точки (0, 0) в точку (1, 2). Но расположение вектора в координатной плоскости не имеет никакого значения, важно лишь его направление и модуль. Таким образом, вектор (0, 0)-(2, 1) - это тот же вектор, что и (1, 0)-(3, 1). Оба вектора имеют координаты (2, 1).

Comment: Вектор тоже имеет две точки, точку откуда направлен и точку куда направлен

Comment: UPD: ну вот я вижу две точки! (0,0) И (2,1) для первого вектора и (1,0) И (3,1) для второго вектора. Попробуйте определить направление вектора когда вам даны всего две величины, например 2 И 5 (для двухмерного пространства)

Comment: @perfect, Прямой ответ на ваш вопрос без объяснений: вторая точка находится в начале координат. Вектор направлен в сторону указанной вами точки.

Comment: @perfect вектор не имеет ни одной точки. Вектор — это набор расстояний или смещений по каждой оси координат. Движение из точки `(1, 0)`  в точку `(3, 1)` — это вектор `(2, 1)`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin (2, 1) это расстояние (размер) вектора, если я ошибаюсь прошу пояснить почему

Comment: @maestro вот этот последний комментарий и есть правильный ответ, я бы так и ответил. То есть точка с координатами 0,0,0

Comment: @perfect не совсем, кватернион в графике для эвклидова пр-ва должен быть единичным, иначе пространство свернется в спираль, эти аргументы помножены на синус половины угла поворота, см. мой ответ.